# Checkbox not styled in Firefox but Chrome fine

Tags: html, css

I have a checkbox which I have styled in css, and not using any of the label selectors. I will be using this on a page which has 10 checkboxes and no labels around them, so can't use any of that code.

I have this working fine with Chrome, but FireFox 29 fails to render the checkboxes properly and I am not sure why!

I have created a code pen here.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ACKrH

HTML

```
<div>
      <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="cb" name="check" checked />
      <label for="cb">My label</label>
</div>
```

CSS

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    -webkit-appearance: none !important;
    -moz-appearance:    none !important;
    appearance:         none !important;
    background-color: #dde1e2;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:active,
input[type="checkbox"]:checked:active {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05), inset 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
    background-color: #5fa8cf;
    border: 1px solid #5fa8cf;
    color: #777;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked:after {
    content: '\2714';
    font-size: 14px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 3px;
    color: white;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Firefox's support for checkbox styling is poor. You won't get them to match the others.

Comment: @JohnConde The thing is it's not even close, it looks like standard styles...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug in Firefox: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=605985

**UPDATE:** I found this: [Custom CSS3 Checkbox doesn't work on Firefox or IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19693872/custom-css3-checkbox-doesnt-work-on-firefox-or-ie?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

```
appearance: none;  /* doesn't work for firefox
```

If you want to style your check boxes. you need to use images for checked and unchecked through JavaScript or jQuery

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=605985