# Checkbox including icon is not showing on Firefox and IE but Safari and Chrome

Tags: css, checkbox, icons

within a page that I develop, I create custom checkboxes including a font and some further css. Actually it is working properly on Chrome and Safari but unfortunately Firefox and IE is not showing the checkboxes at all. First I thought that :after or :before might be the issue, but finally I could not solve it.
I created an example. This example is working on Chrome (it is not showing the font in Chrome - in the real version it is showing it), Safari is actually showing the font. But the real problem is, that **IE and Firefox is not showing it at all** (independent if with or without font).

https://jsfiddle.net/chejxapq/1/

```
#checkicons input[type=checkbox]{
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

#checkicons input[type=checkbox]:checked:after, input[type=checkbox]:after{
  visibility: visible;
  font-family: Flaticon;
  font-size:50px;
  margin-left: 36px;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

#checkicons input[type=checkbox]:checked:after{
  color: white;
  border: solid black;
  background-color: #1e6e11;
  border-width: 1px;
}

#checkicons input[type=checkbox]:after{
  color: #1e6e11;
  border: solid #1e6e11;
  background-color: white;
  border-width: 1px;
}


@font-face {
    font-family: "Flaticon";
    src: url("fonts/flaticon.eot");
    src: url("fonts/flaticon.eot#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("fonts/flaticon.woff") format("woff"),
    url("fonts/flaticon.ttf") format("truetype"),
    url("fonts/flaticon.svg") format("svg");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
[class^="flaticon-"]:before, [class*=" flaticon-"]:before,
[class^="flaticon-"]:after, [class*=" flaticon-"]:after {
    font-family: Flaticon;

    }.flaticon-oven:after {
        content: "\e000";
    }
}


<div id="checkicons">
    <input type="checkbox" class="flaticon-oven" id="oven" name="oven" onchange="toggleDiv(this)"></input><br>
</div>
```

Comment: Does not anyone have any idea?

Comment: Still did not fixed the problem :-/ Any input of you guys?

Comment: - Its a known bug in firefox. read here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19693872/custom-css3-checkbox-doesnt-work-on-firefox-or-ie?rq=1